# calculate worst case time to find variable x in memory

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, tlb

I have question from exam but I don't understand the solution, can someone explain the solution for me ?

Memory access time =`2.5*10^-7 sec`

second memory time = `3*10^-6`

TLB time = `10^-8`

Given virtual address,value x and 3 level page table, how much time it takes to read x value from memory in the worst case?

the solution is : `10^-8 + 2.5*10^-7 + 3*(3*10^-6 + 2*2.5*10^-7) + 10^-8 = 1076*10^-7`

Comment: I'd like to know what school asks useless questions like this on exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that the solution is performing 2 TLB lookups, 7 memory accesses, and 3 secondary memory accesses.

Here are the steps in the process:

1)  The CPU accesses the TLB to find the memory location that the virtual address maps to.

2)  The CPU accesses main memory to look for the virtual address.  This step fails.

3)  The CPU accesses the page file (1 memory access to get the page file, 1 more to access the page file entry).

4)  The CPU reads from secondary memory to get the page referred to in the page file.

5)  Repeat steps 3 & 4 for each level in the page table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula as far as I know to calculate best and worst times of memory accesses. However, there are various factors that influence it:

- The width of the access. On 32-bit x86, 8-bit and 32-bit accesses tend to be faster than 16-bit ones.
- Whether the access is aligned or not. Unaligned accesses tend to be slower than aligned accesses.
- Whether accessed memory is cached. Accesses to cached memory are faster than accesses to uncached memory.
- The NUMA domain of the accessed memory. Accessing memory belonging to a close NUMA domain is faster than accessing memory belonging to a far NUMA domain.
- Whether paging is enabled. Accessing memory when paging is enabled involves traversing paging structures and therefore is slower.
- The type of memory. For example, writing to video memory is slower than writing to "normal" memory. Respectively, reading from video memory is much much much slower than reading from "normal" memory.
- Other factors I forgot to mention. It's hard to memorise them all.

Furthermore, the influence of each of these factors depends on the underlaying hardware, therefore it would be really hard to invent even an approximation formula that calculates best and worst times of memory accesses.